# ngx-toastr issue with Angular version

Tags: angular, npm

I tried to use ngx-toastr with angular 7. But when I try to install it I got error like the one seen below. I don't know what the problem is with the Angular version?

`admin$ npm link ngx-toastr --save`

npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Do you mean `npm install ngx-toastr --save`?

Comment: yes...I already installed it globally...Thats y i use 'link' here

Comment: Already i am using angular 7.But i got warning like i am not having Angular 6 & 7 version.. "npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed"

Comment: As mentioned on the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr this package is compatible with angular4 and angular5, they haven't tested it with angular7 yet and haven't updated their library to support angular7 that's the reason npm throws a warning. Update the toaster library to latest version Play with the library if nothing breaks ignore the warning

Comment: For Angular 7, I have been using `angular2-toaster`. I didn't try with `ngx-toastr `.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for your reply..I will try to use 'angular2-toaster'

Comment: https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/573        i saw this..Thats Y i tried this with angular 6 & 7..but both didnot work